# Big O Notation Confusion

Tags: java

Ordering from smallest to largest and wondering where I have made errors? Equivalents are on the same line. I'm really confused about where O(sqrt(n)) would fall on the list?

```
1. O(log n)
2. O(n)
3. O(2^2 n)
4. O(2n log n)
5. O(n log n)
6. O(n log n^2)
7. O(sqrt(n))
8. O(n^1.5) 
9. O(n^2)   O(2n^2)  O(n^2 log n)
10. O(n^3)
11. O(k^2) O(2^n)
```

Comment: You've made other errors as well. I personally don't mind helping you if you provide your calculations based on which you ordered these items. You must have made a mistake in your calculations, and it's more productive (for you in the first place) to point you out errors than solve your HW for you.

Comment: Your questions indicate that you either don't know or don't understand definition of Big-O. Or you don't understand how to work with the definition. You definitely should try to understand it. Rigorously prove some simple cases first: `n = O(n)`, `2n = O(n)`, `100 = O(n)`, `n = O(n log n)`, `n^2 * 100 = O(n^3)`. It's much better than trying to guess the answers or getting answers from others. For your ordering it should be true that `ans[i]= O(ans[i+1])`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`O( )`  omitted for convenience:

```
k^2 (assuming k is constant??)  
log n 
sqrt n == n^0.5   
n == (2^2) n   
n log n == 2n log n == n log(n^2)   
n^1.5  
n^2 == 2n^2  
n^2 log n  
n^3  
2^n
```

Comment: k is constant, thank you for your help. I have questions. So I am going by this

Comment: k is constant, thank you for your help. I have questions. n == 2^2 n because you drop the constant? the same is true for n^2 == 2n^2? I guess I'm confused why does n^2 log n come after n^2? I've graphed it, but I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: yeah you drop constant factors. O(log n) > O(1) multiply both sides by `n^2` and you get O(n^2 log n) > O(n^2)

Comment: can you help me understand why k^2 is the smallest? I know that we drop constants, but I thought this would be further down the list

Comment: is it just simply because it is a constant?

Comment: a constant is smaller than any complexity that depends on `n` because (informally) no matter what constant you choose I can always tune my `n` to be bigger than your chosen k. Try graphing

Comment: n! would be at the very bottom of my list?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, in better understanding the order of complexites.

[image]

Comment: thank you, i have graphed them, and some are very easy to see, but there are others that I am struggling with

Comment: struggling with like?

Comment: i used this list from smallest to largest (constant, log, polylogarithmic, linear, quadratic, polynomial, exponential) and I know that k^2, k is a constant, but you are still squaring it and when I graphed it, it didnt seem like it should be the smallest?

Comment: While determining the complexity, we neglect the constant part and only take into account the variable part. So, you have `11. O(k^2) O(2^n)`, where `k` is a constant. Then you can easily avoid it unless the constant is huge. It is simply same as `O(2^n)`.

Comment: thank you. i do appreciate this graph, i am not just trying to be fed answers, but i was truly stumped with this notation. Clearly i need more practice

Comment: new member, so i upvoted it, but it doesn't count until my reputation hits 15